# Wallet.createRandom() function by ethers.js don't work in a React Native Project

Tags: ethers.js, wallets, react, mnemonic

i'm trying to make a wallet in react native using ethers.js, but when i'm trying to call the function createRandom, to generate a secure random seed the application gets crashed.

this is the code, i'm using this in a react Context but also when i just the function Wallet.createRandom(), it also gets stoped.

```
const initWallet = async () => {

    console.log( wallet.currAccount )

    if ( !wallet.currAccount ) {

        
        try {

            const account = ethers.Wallet.createRandom()

            const encryptAccount = await account.encrypt( password )


            const assets: Assets = {
                1: [TokenItems[0]]
            }

            dispatch({ 
                type: 'create_account', 
                payload: { name: 'Account 1', wallet: encryptAccount, assets }
            })

            console.log( wallet.currAccount )
            
        } catch (error) {

            console.log( error )

        }


    }
```

Does anyone know why this happen?